# "in order for ... to ..." VS "for ... to ..."

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, infinitive-clauses

I have the following in my documents:
**(1a)** *A mother was permanently having to watch her child **for him** not to spill the bottle down himself*. — incorrect — Is it so?
**(1b)** *A mother was permanently having to watch her child **in order for him** not to spill the bottle down himself*. — correct — Is it so?

---

[collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bound):
**(2a)** *The dog came bounding back with the stick **for Richard** to throw again*.

Does (2a) mean (2b)?:
**(2b)** *The dog came bounding back with the stick **in order for Richard** to throw again*.
If not, then what does (2a) mean?
If it does, then why (2a) is correct whereas (1a) is not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, (2a) and (2b) effectively mean the same,  but I would change (2b) to *in order for Richard to throw* **it** *again*.

I consider (1b) grammatically correct but not particularly idiomatic. I would prefer *to make sure he didn't spill the bottle* or *for fear he should spill the bottle*, for example.

Comment: Hi! I upvoted your good answer! Thank you very much for everything!